# How to find the position of repeated elements in a list, then sum those elements?

Tags: python, list

I want to find the position of the repeated elements in the column "1" and the column "2" in a specified matrix "x" (the matrix "x" has a nx3 size ("n" is the maximum number between the column "1" and the column "2", in the next example is max(3,4)=4)), for then in the principal diagonal (number 1 to "n") of a new matrix "z"(the matrix "z" has a "n"x"n" size) sum the values for each column (except the columns with values equal to zero), and put the respective values off-diagonal in the respective column. This is an example of a matrix "x":

```
        1 2 3
x=  1 [[1,2,4],
    2  [1,3,2],
    3  [2,3,1],
    4  [3,4,5]]
```

The matrix "z" is a symmetric matrix, meaning for example the element z[1,2] is equal to z[2,1] and the element z[1,3] is equal to z[3,1].This is the structure of the matrix "z":

```
z=  [[z[1],z[1 to 2],z[1 to 3],z[1 to 4]], 
     [z[2 to 1],z[2],z[2 to 3],z[2 to 4]], 
     [[z[3 to 1],z[3 to 2],z[3],z[3 to 4]],
     [[z[4 to 1],z[4 to 2],z[4 to 3],z[4]]
```

The elements in the diagonal principal( for this example are):

```
 z[1]=z[1 to 2]+z[1 to 3]+z[1 to 4]
 z[2]=z[2 to 1]+z[2 to 3]+z[2 to 4]
 z[3]=z[3 to 1]+z[3 to 2]+z[3 to 4]
 z[4]=z[4 to 1]+z[4 to 2]+z[4 to 3]
```

The desired matrix (for this example) is:

```
z=  [[4+2=6,4,2,0], 
     [4,4+1=5,1,0], 
     [2,1,2+1+5=8,5],
     [0,0,5,5]]
```

Note: The zeros in the matrix "z" represent if there aren´t connection with the other numbers. In this example the number "4" has only connection with the number "3"(the value is 5). Then the connection for the number 4 with the number 1 and number 2 are zero.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: You will also have to clarify your question.  How do you derive "5+6"?  Where does the "2" come from at z[1][0]?

Comment: I´m sorry, I saw the error in the matrix. Thank you.

Comment: It is obscure how you leap from the number 1 being in two rows to something involving 3 and 5. Where did 3 and 5 come from. You haven't clearly described how matrix z is to be derived from matrix x.

Comment: Questions that need to be clarified: How is x represented -- as a list of rows, where each row is a list?  If so -- you should *start* by transposing it. Is x always a 3 by 3 matrix? Do the numbers 1-3 always appear exactly twice in the first two columns? The sums are apparently drawn from the last column -- something which you never said and which is implicitly contradicted by your use of the phrase "these values" (which grammatically refers to the repeated elements in the first two columns, not the non-repeated values in the third.)

Comment: Hi John, I agree with you. Here is a better explanation. The matrix "z" is a square matrix,  the size of matrix "z" depends of the maximum value of the column "0" and the maximum value of the column "1" ( in this example, the maximum value of the column "0" is "3" and the maximum value of the column "1" is "3", so the maximum value between "3" and "3" is "3",  and the matrix has a size of 3x3). The matrix "x" can have "n" rows. The numbers in the column "0" and the column "1" for each row can´t be equal (e.g can´t be 1-1).

Comment: The search of the repeated elements is only in the column "0" and the column "1"(is like a connectivity matrix). In the above example, in the first row, the number "1" appears in the row 0(column 0) and the row 1 (column 0). So for the position z[0,0] the sum is 3+5=8. Then the elements are z[0,1]=3 and z[0,2]=5. The number "2" appears in the row 0(column 1) and row 2 (column 1). So for the position z[1,1] the sum is 3+6=9. Then the elements are z[1,0]=3 and z[1,2]=6. The number "3" appears in the row 1(column 1) and row 2(column 0). So for the position z[2,2] the sum is 5+6=11...

Comment: Then the elements are z[2,0]=5 and z[2,1]=6. It´s important to say "the matrix "z" is symmetrical matrix, e.g. the element z[0,1] is equal to z[1,0]. Thank you.

Comment: @JUSR This helps (though perhaps belongs more as an edit to your question rather than a comment) but leaves certain things unclear. For one thing -- you have given a description of diagonal elements, but not the off-diagonal elements. I can see how you do it for 3x3, but what if `x` is 4x3 or 5x3? If `n` is the maximum element in columns 0,1 is it always the case that the numbers 1,2,...,`n` each appear exactly twice in those columns? Your description suggests that but doesn't say it. Perhaps you could edit your question, with examples illustrating cases with more than 3 elements.

Comment: Hi @JohnColeman I corrected the description of the problem. Again thanks for your comments.

Comment: @JUSR It is still underdetermined. For example -- where did those zeros in z come from? They aren't in x. Also -- your description of "the structure of z" itself involves z. What do you even *mean* by "z[4 to 1]"?

Comment: I @JohnColeman, that zeros describes if exist a conection between the numbers for example the element z[4 to 1] or z[1 to 4] refers if exist a connection between the number 1 and number 4 (in this case there aren´t).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is clarified if you introduce graph-theoretic terminology. Your `x` could be thought of as describing a weighted graph. A row like `[1,3,2]` can be interpreted as describing the existence of an edge of weight 2 connecting node 1 and node 3. The matrix `z` contains the following information:

1) For each node `i`, the corresponding diagonal entry is the sum of the weights of all edges which are incident with `i`.

2) For each pair of distinct nodes `i` and `j`, the corresponding entry of `z` is either `0` if the nodes are not connected, or the weight of the edge connecting `i` and `j` if they are (or sum of the weights if there are multiple edges).

Given this interpretation, things are easy enough. The following assumes that the nodes in `x` begin with `1`. Note that the resulting matrix is 0-based even though the graph is 1-based, so to find the weight from node 2 to node 3 you will need `z[1][2]`:

```
def makeMatrix(edges):
    n = max(max(edge[:2]) for edge in edges)
    z = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]
    for edge in edges:
        i,j,w = edge
        z[i-1][i-1] += w
        z[j-1][j-1] += w
        z[i-1][j-1] += w
        z[j-1][i-1] += w
    return z
```

The following helps for debugging:

```
def pprint(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        print(' '.join(str(i) for i in row))
```

For example,

```
>>> x = [[1,2,4],[1,3,2],[2,3,1],[3,4,5]]
>>> z = makeMatrix(x)
>>> pprint(z)
6 4 2 0
4 5 1 0
2 1 8 5
0 0 5 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @John Coleman. Can you recommend me a good book for graph theory?. Again thanks.

Comment: @JUSR My favorite is "Pearls in Graph Theory" by Hartsfield and Ringel (which now seems to be an inexpensive Dover paperback). It has a somewhat mathematical approach. If you are primarily a programmer, you might benefit from a more algorithmic approach. Just search on Amazon for a bit, reading the customer reviews.

Comment: Thanks @John Coleman. I hope to keep in touch with you, thanks again.

Comment: @JUSR You are welcome. My email address is on my profile